# Sum OR average OR max elements of two lists according to a third list defining the operation

Tags: python

I have 3 lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = ['SUM','AVG','MAX']
```

I need to achieve:

```
d = [5,3.5,6]
```

Note that a and b are just an example. In reality **I have a few hundred arrays** with about one hundred elements. So I would prefer an interesting "Pythonian way" to achieve the d array, rather than looping around.
Something like similar to `map`, for example:

```
d= [calculate(c, x) for x in [a,b]]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: where is c coming from?

Comment: c is the list #3. If the 'calculate' is possible, 'c' would be given to the iterator to know what to do to each index of the 'a' and 'b' lists (at least this is my idea... not sure if its possible...)

Comment: When we use map, for example: [map(int, x) for x in list] we are mapping x to cast for an integer. What I am asking is: instead of casting to a type (in this case an integer), we could 'cast' to a predefined operation. Of course 'a', 'b' and 'c' would have the same size.

Comment: Are you saying you have a hundred different functions? Or are you arbitrarily repeating functions as unless all your lists are exactly the same size including c then zipping is not going to work

Comment: What should happen for different length lists?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham , in this case, in my case, it is not a problem. they will have the same lenght. I describe in more detail what I needed (and seems to be solved by Tom Karzes answer).

I have some calculation for ~150 variables (of a forest model) that have a daily output. I need to calculate for each month that variable, of course in the same way. So, for each month, I filter my daily results for a specific month and calculate MAX,SUM,AVG, etc predefined for each variable. For example precipitation will be SUM, Tree height will be MAX, and so on. The nr of days will differ each month.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do this:

```
op_dict = {
    'SUM' : lambda x, y: x + y,
    'AVG' : lambda x, y: (x + y) / 2.0,
    'MAX' : max
}

a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = ['SUM','AVG','MAX']

d = [op_dict[z](x, y) for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)]
```

Here's a more powerful version that can handle any number of lists, but they must still all be the same length:

```
op_dict = {
    'SUM' : lambda *x: sum(x),
    'AVG' : lambda *x: sum(x) / float(len(x)),
    'MAX' : max
}

ops = ['SUM', 'AVG', 'MAX']
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]
d = [10, 11, 12]

args = [ops, a, b, c, d]

r = [op_dict[x[0]](*x[1:]) for x in zip(*args)]
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the suggestion. I need to emphasize that I have hundreds or lists (I **formated as bold in the question**). So if I have, for example 10 lists, does this mean that your d solution would be:
`d = [op_dict[z](x, y) for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)]` ?

would it be possible to change this to send a, ..., j in a list?

Comment: You'd need to also increase the arguments.  For example, to add one more list, you could do `[op_dict[w](x, y, z) for x, y, z, w in zip(a, b, c, d)`.  The lambda functions would also need to take more than 2 arguments.

Comment: Why  not just use `sum`? Also if the lists are not the same length you will lose data.

Comment: @Padraic because `sum` doesn't accept two arguments.  It wants a list.  And yes, of course it's assumed that the lists are all the same length.

Comment: Hum... not yet what I need, but the concept helps... I really need something more flexible to consider an "irregular nr of lists" (each list will differ depending on the nr of days in a month). So the opt_dict should be flexible to accept different arguments (depends on nr days of each month) and 'd' syntax should be flexible to accept different nr of lists (e.g. a list of lists)

Comment: Hmm, I can definitely generalize this to handle any number of lists, but are you saying the individual lists may have different lengths?  In that case, would you just want to ignore the missing elements?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a version that can handle any number of lists, but it still has the requirement that they all be the same length.

Comment: Works like a charm! :

Comment: In fact, what I have is a list that can vary in size according to the nr of days in a month. Each element of that array has a fixed length. Each element of the last list is calculated the same way. So I change a,b,c,d to `lsts = [a,b,c,d]` that I build à priori, I can then use `lsts.insert(0, ops)` and use `r = [op_dict[x[0]](*x[1:]) for x in zip(*lsts)]` ... worked like a charm :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: What if the lists are empty? `AVG` will fail.

Comment: @Peter you need to screen out empty lists before invoking this.  There is no such thing as the average of an empty set of numbers (it's meaningless), so there is nothing it could do other than return None or NaN anyway.  The same goes for `MAX` (for which Python gives an error).

Answer (score 1):

If you have less functions than elements in the lists you can cycle the functions:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = ['SUM', 'AVG', 'MAX']

mapped = {'SUM': sum, 'AVG': lambda x: sum(x, 0.0) / len(x), 'MAX': max}

from itertools import cycle


def calc(funcs, *args):
    _fncs = list(map(mapped.get, funcs))
    return [f(it) for f, it in zip(cycle(_fncs), zip(*args))]
```

If c is shorter than a and b then the functions will be cycled, if the lists are different lengths you can use `itertools.izip_longest` but you will have to decide what an appropriate fillvalue is.

If you are using python 3 there is also a builtin for the average:

```
mapped = {'SUM': sum, 'AVG': mean, 'MAX': max}

from itertools import cycle

from statistics import mean

def calc(funcs, *args):
    _fncs = list(map(mapped.get, funcs))
    return [f(it) for f, it in zip(cycle(_fncs), zip(*args))]
```

If they are always going to be even lengths you don't need the cycle:

```
def calc(funcs, *args):
    _fncs = map(mapped.get, funcs)
    return [f(it) for f, it in zip(_fncs, zip(*args))]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b
def avg(a, b):
    return a + b / 2.0

def calculate(a, b, c):
    mapping = {'SUM': sum,
               'AVG': avg,
               'MAX': max}
    return mapping[c](a,b)

d = [calculate(a1,b1,c1) for a1,b1,c1 in zip(a, b, c)]
```

So, working from the bottom up:

- Zip is great for iterating through multiple lists at once. a1,b1,c1 are the items in a, b, and c at the same index.
- Calculate will do a different calculation depending on c.
- the mapping dict simply stores functions ( notice the lack of parens, we don't call the function. We are storing the function itself. )
- The we grab the correct function, determined by the key we pass in, and call it with two arguments.

edit: I love how we've all given essentially the same answer, within a small period of time. Kinda reassures you that this is the way to do it.

Obviously syntatic sugar like lambdas help keep the code looking simpler.

Comment: Why do you define your own `sum()` function?  There is already one built into the Python language.

Comment: @zondo `sum` takes an iterable.